# Rails validating post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, post

Is there a gem or easy way to validate a API post request? For example I am always expecting a field to be either present or always a string and if it is not to ignore the request all together.

Or is the only way to do this is to manually check each request coming in with an IF statement?

Comment: in your controller you could do, request.post?

Comment: That's what model validations are for. Add the validations and return back the errors. Its not a good idea to ignore the request because a service should always respond with proper error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the request check the params in the controller and if the params are the way you need them to be allow post -> create/update your db records if not return nil to the post request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign a Model to your "request". This way you could "validate" presence of any given fields